# How to add space between buttons when elements added in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form where at the end of which, the user can dynamically add an input (text) field. When they click the 'add field' button, an input field and a Delete button appear. The next element to show is then the Save button which is used to submit the form data to the server.

Usually I would create elements in HTML but to generate the new input field and delete button I did this inside a function using Javascript.

Now I'm just stuck on how to add some space between the Delete button and the Save button. It's not an ideal layout, but I'd like to at least get the Save button to be under the Delete button. At the moment the Save button is right beside the Delete button.

Here is the function in JS:

```
function addField() {
       // Creating the input field
        const newInputField = document.createElement("input");
        newInputField.type = "text";
        newInputField.name = "field"
        newInputField.id = "field";

        // Creating the minus button element
        const minus = document.createElement("input");
        minus.type = "button"
        minus.name = "minus_button"
        minus.id = "minus_button"
        minus.setAttribute("onclick", "deleteField(this)");
        const minusText = document.createTextNode("-");
        minus.appendChild(minusText);

        // add elements to the DOM
        sub_button = document.getElementById('submit')
        myForm.appendChild(minus)
        myForm.appendChild(newInputField);
        myForm.insertBefore(newInputField, sub_button);
        sub_button.style.margin = "10px";
        myForm.insertBefore(minus, sub_button);
```

This was my attempt to add space between the delete button and save button but it isn't working:

```
        br = document.createElement("span");
        br.innerHTML = "<br/>";
        document.body.appendChild(br);
       
    }
```

Comment: First, it looks like every time you create the newinput and minus elements you are reusing the same ID. This isn't a problem with the spacing but is a problem as IDs must be unique.

Comment: If the submit button is in HTML, just wrap it in a div. With an element wrapping the submit button, you can adjust its style for margins and stuff too

Comment: @imvain2 Do you mean for the case that there are more than one of each? Also, thank you for that tip re wrapping it in a div! I've added a line break for now but it will be better for sure to have that styling in the HTML div.

Comment: Anytime **addField** is ran, new elements reusing the SAME ID are created.

Comment: Will fix that: thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to add the HTML markup as well in your post, as it's not clear exactly what the current layout is.

Adding to the comments above, I definitely agree that styling the button's margins (or the div that contains it) with CSS is the way to go as the layout is always best done in CSS.

If you find it easier, you could also design your buttons in the HTML code and then hide them with the css property *display:none*.  In JS, you can hide/unhide with *document.getElementById("buttonId").style.display = "none"* (to hide) or *"inline"* (to show). There are other options too for that property.